# How can I know the number of solutions of an equation involving prime numbers?

Tags: plotting, prime-numbers

I have to admit that I am totally noob to mathematica, and I have a question for which I have not found any easy-to-understand answer about.

How could I calculate the number of prime numbers of a certain form (like, for example, $4n+1$ or $4p+1$ being $p$ prime) lower than a given input $N$? Would there be any way to plot it respect to that $N$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Number of primes*

```
n = 10000;
primes = Prime[Range[PrimePi[n]]];

(* 4n + 1 *)
pickQ = Divisible[primes - 1, 4];
Length@ Pick[primes, pickQ]

(* 4p + 1 with p prime *)
pickQ2 = PrimeQ[(primes - 1) / 4];
Length@ Pick[primes, pickQ2]
```

*Plots*

```
(* 4n + 1 *)
nbprimes[n_] := With[{primes = Prime[Range[PrimePi[n]]]},
    Length@ Pick[primes, Divisible[primes - 1, 4]]
];

DiscretePlot[nbprimes[n], {n, 1, 100}]
```

[image]

```
(* 4p + 1 with p prime *)
nbprimes2[n_] := With[{primes = Prime[Range[PrimePi[n]]]},
    Length@ Pick[primes, PrimeQ[(primes - 1)/4]]
];

DiscretePlot[nbprimes2[n], {n, 1, 100}]
```

[image]